# (Reactjs) Persist html file with styling to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docx

I am working on a React app which allows users to drag and drop UI elements to generate a template. At the end of the process, we have an HTML preview of the template displayed to the user.
 What would be the best way to save this HTML (along with the styling) to the server ? A few approaches we tried:

1. Convert HTML to string and persist. This makes it difficult to import these templates at a later point in time (and extract the react components out of it)
2. Store all the HTML and styling data in some JSON format. But there is just too much to store (all the margins, padding values etc.)

Any ideas?

**EDIT :** The reason I am asking this is because there might be a totally different way of storing templates server side which I might be unaware of. For example, we currently store .docx files as templates. They provide an easy way of representing (and visualising) all the styling info of the document. And it is convenient to just save the docx file, than to parse through the HTML and extract all the styling info into a JSON. Now we are doing away with .docx because of some business limitations.

Comment: "there is just too much to store" - So? If someone gave me the requirement to store 10TB worth of data, and that logically made sense, store 10TB worth of data. If you need all that information to regenerate the content, then it's not too much; it is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Gregg I have edited my question to explain the question more.